# How to fix npm npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:123:443?

Tags: reactjs, npm, proxy

I'm starting to learn React js and I'm trying to create my first app. When typing the command npm create vite@latest or npm create vite@latest my-app, or npm create-react-app my-app I get the same or similar error.

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:123:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-04T15_54_15_416Z-debug-0.log
```

I didn't know how a proxy works so I did some research and found these commands:

`npm config get proxy`

- null

`npm config get https-proxy`

- undefined

I tried to fix the problem with npm delete cache, also with npm config delete proxy, netsh winsock reset, netsh int ip reset, ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew, and ipconfig /flushdns, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

It worked for me.